# Shutdown nokia series 40 phone if sim is changed

Tags: security, qt, java-me, nokia-s40

I need to restrict only a particular sim on a given phone (nokia 2700) such that the phone is not usable if the sim is changed. I'm thinking of either preventing the sim from registering on the network or having some background app that will shutdown the phone or prevent usage if the sim is change.

QT (new to it) and JavaMe suggestions are both fine.

How  do I proceed with this?

Edit1:
The idea is to prevent the user of the phone from changing the sim card. The phone should not work if the sim card is changed. For this, I need a way of notifying this and either shutting down the phone or doing something to prevent it from being used.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt is not supported on Series 40 phones. It is available for Symbian and MeeGo based Nokia phones. Check this [list](http://www.developer.nokia.com/search/search.xhtml?view=ds&k=&ob=pubdate&p1=fn%3atype&c1=must&o1=EQ&v1=fnType%3aTerminal&p9=dp%3adevelopment_technology&c9=must&o9=EQ&v9=dpDevelopmentTechnology%3aqt) for supported models.

In order to achieve this you need to be able to detect a sim card and prevent phone from functioning if necessary.

On Series 40 JavaME, there are a few [system.properties](http://library.developer.nokia.com/topic/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-A1F90B63-5F14-4829-BCA1-A23B925CF670.html) that you can use to detect the current sim card. There are no events for receiving the sim card change. Some of the properties are restricted to manufacturer and operator security domains. Unfortunately, *com.nokia.mid.imsi* which identifies a particular sim card is one of those. However *com.nokia.mid.networkid* is not restricted and should be sufficient to identify a particular network(If that is your purpose).

There is no JavaME way of blocking the use of the phone (I guess that is the point with Java security and sandboxing). Also the ability to start an app. at the boot and keep it running on the background is restricted to manufacturer and operator signing on Series 40 phones.

Answer (score 0):

The phone should have this function already.

From the manual (page 12):

> **Access codes**
>
> The security code helps to protect your phone against
>   unauthorised use. The preset code is **12345**. You can create and change
>   the code, and set the phone to request the code. Keep the code secret
>   and in a safe place separate from your phone. If you forget the code
>   and your phone is locked, your phone will require service and
>   additional charges may apply. For more information, contact a Nokia
>   Care point or your phone dealer. The PIN code supplied with the SIM
>   card protects the card against unauthorised use. The PIN2 code
>   supplied with some SIM cards is required to access certain services.
>   If you enter the PIN or PIN2 code incorrectly three times in
>   succession, you are asked for the PUK or PUK2 code. If you do not have
>   them, contact your service provider. The module PIN is required to
>   access the information in the security module of your SIM card. The
>   signing PIN may be required for the digital signature. The barring
>   password is required when using the call barring service. To set how
>   your phone uses the access codes and security settings, select **Menu >
>   Settings > Security.**

I used to have a Sony-Ericsson phone that had the same function and it allowed the access code to be saved on the sim card. The phone would not ask for the access code unless the sim was changed. I hope you can find the same function in the Security menu on your Nokia phone.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry if the question was not very straight forward. The idea here is to prevent the user from changing the sim card. At such, the phone should not work if the sim card is changed.

Comment: If the user doesn't know the access code the phone won't work with another sim card.

Comment: that is a valid point but if he/she accidentally does something does something  and the phone is lock, the problem will be unlocking the phone. In this case, you they have to come to the office to have it unlocked?